# How to make Flutter BottomAppBar with CircularNotch in center?

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

In Flutter, I wanted to create a circular notch in the bottom navigation bar but my icons are in SVG and available plugins only take the icon data. something like these.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this package at Pub.dev

https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Take a look at styles 15 & 16.

Answer (score 0):

Use the package footer and customise as you needed. This package is available in pub.dev. Here is the link https://pub.dev/packages/footer.

This footer will take widgets as  `child:` so you can return a `Scaffold ()` or `container()`